# ScriptDb remaining quota

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to find out what your remaining ScriptDb quota is?
(Adding records until i fill the scriptDb just doesn't seem like a good way to find out your db's limitations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature isn't currently available. The Apps Script team is looking to make this data available via the quota dashboard sometime in one of the next few releases.

If you need access to this programmatically, it'd be a good idea to file a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) in our issues tracker.